# ruby-on-rails server crashes with 'incompatible library version'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a new installation of ruby on rails on a recently updated mac, with the most recent version of ruby installed on it. I created my first new rails application, with the command:`rails new blog`

The app was created without any error messages. However, when I move into the new directory and run `bin/rails server` the server build fails with a long list of error messages:

```
/Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/lib/debug_inspector.rb:6:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/lib/debug_inspector.bundle (fatal)
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/lib/debug_inspector.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7.2/lib/binding_of_caller/mri2.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7.2/lib/binding_of_caller/mri2.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7.2/lib/binding_of_caller.rb:9:in `require'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7.2/lib/binding_of_caller.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from /Users/antony1/Documents/Ruby/Rails/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/antony1/Documents/Ruby/Rails/blog/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/antony1/Documents/Ruby/Rails/blog/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/antony1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/antony1/Documents/Ruby/Rails/blog/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I've run `gem pristine --all` and made sure that my gems were up to date, but I am still unable to get this to work. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you remove the debug_inspector dependency and try again?

Comment: That got me started on the right path. The first line of the error message changed. I then installed the debug_inspector, and ran gem pristine --all. I tried to call up the server again, and was told that actionpack was missing, and to run bundle install. After doing that, I was told that debug_inspector was missing from the dependencies. I wiped the app and tried to generate a new one. That returned an error message saying that actionpack was missing. I installed actionpack, made a new app, and was able to call the server without any problem. I have no idea what went wrong, or how I fixed it.

Comment: Interesting ... perhaps you can run `gem dependency debug_inspector -R` to show which gems are depending on debug_inspector (I never have heard of it). Perhaps that can provide an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

After intializing a rails app, especially when you edit the Gemfile file, you need to run, it's generally a good idea to run `bundle install` to establish all the dependencies. Have you done that that?

Comment: Tried it just now, it did not work. It failed with the same set of errors.

Comment: Can you run `gem update` and then `bundle install`? @AntonySerio

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see that last line in your post. Have you altered anything since you created the app?

Comment: It did not appear to have any effect. There were no gems to update, and bundle-install had the same output as it did the last time I ran it. The server still fails with the same errors.

Comment: No I did not change anything after creating the app. Today is my first day working with rails.